# Stop jquery from adding links…

Tags: jquery, if-statement

i have a function that is supposed to create a button on every time a element is cloned. The problem is that it is adding a button to all elements within that div even though there already is one. I sure this is a simple task but just cant get my head around it.

```
<h1>skapa ett moment</h1>

<?php foreach($rows as $r) : ?>

    <div class="span6 part">
        <button id="add_part" class="btn-mini btn pull-right">Lägg till</button>
        <div class="moment_content">
            <h1 class="part_heading"><?php echo $r->title; ?></h1>
            <h4 id="id" style="display:none;" class="pull-left"><?php echo $r->id;?></h4>
            <div class=""><?php echo $r->content; ?></div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="result" class="span3 pull-right">
    </div>

<?php endforeach; ?>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        var knapp = $('.part').find('.btn').hide();
        $('.part').hover(function(){
            $(this).toggleClass('well');
            $(this).children('.btn').toggle();
        });


        $('button#add_part').on('click', function(){
            var add = $(this).next().clone().appendTo('#result');
            if ($('<a class="btn-mini pull-right btn" href="#">ta bort</a>').length > 0)
            {
                $('<a class="btn-mini pull-right btn" href="#">ta bort</a>').insertBefore('#result .part_heading');
            } 
            if ($('<a class="btn-mini pull-right btn" href="#">ta bort</a>').length > 1){
                $('#result a.btn').remove();
            } 
        });


    </script>
```

Comment: You're cloning elements with an `id` => multiple elements with the same id => **INVALID HTML.** There are other issues with your code, but this is the most important one,

Comment: And what's your HTML look like? Can we see [a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/)?

Comment: Allthough i just appending it to a div with an id no creating several id's.

Comment: No; you seem to have added the php. Could you render the page in a browser, then 'view source' and post the relevant portion of the HTML. Anything including `<?php` `foreach(...)` and `?>` is *rarely* HTML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do something like this [jsBin live example](http://jsbin.com/equgib/4/edit#javascript,html)

To work, you need some changes:

- remove all `id`'s
- add `btn-add-part` as a class to the button
- change the `<h4>` with the removable link
- if you want to access the added `id`'s, I have included the `data-content-id` as part of the `<div>` block
- put the `<div id="result">` outside your loop (as I'm assuming that's what you want after all

I also have styled a little bit to be easier to follow up...

The jQuery code is essentially:

```
$(function(){

  // hide all "ADD" buttons
  $(".btn-add-part").hide();

  // on mouse over .part
  $(".part").hover(function() {
      $(this).toggleClass("well").find(".btn-add-part").stop().fadeToggle();
    });

  // on "ADD" click
  $(".btn-add-part").click(function() {
    // clone DOM block
    var block = $(this).closest(".part").find(".moment_content").clone(); 
    // show remove link
    block.find(".btn-rem-part").show(); 
    // append to result
    block.appendTo("#result"); 
  });

  // on "REMOVE" click
  $(".btn-rem-part").live("click", function() {
    $(this).closest(".moment_content").fadeOut("slow", function() { 
       // Now that faded, let's remove it...
       $(this).remove(); 
    });
  });

});
```

---

**Added Save Button**

```
  // on "SAVE"
  $(".btn-Save").click(function() {
    // empty?
    if($("#result").length > 0) {

      var r = "";
      $("#result").find(".moment_content").each(function() {
        // for each block added
        if(r.length > 0) r += ", ";
        r += $(this).attr("data-content-id");
      });

      alert("Submiting the following ID's: " + r);
      return true;

    }
    alert('Nothing to save...');
    return false;
  });
```

Comment: Thank you, all of you! balexandre's post did just the trick for me!